Arduino IDE 2.3.2 Not Launching New Install
I just installed the Arduino IDE on a new computer from the installer. It opens a window and the arduino icon pulses but never seems to do anything. I ran it from the powershell and got a bunch of errors.
Any idea how to fix the library_index.json not existing?
PowerShell 7.4.2
PS C:\Program Files\Arduino IDE> & '.\Arduino IDE.exe'

PS C:\Program Files\Arduino IDE> Arduino IDE 2.3.2
Checking for frontend application configuration customizations. Module path: C:\Program Files\Arduino IDE\resources\app\lib\backend\electron-main.js, destination 'package.json': C:\Program Files\Arduino IDE\resources\app\package.json
Setting 'theia.frontend.config.appVersion' application configuration value to: "2.3.2" (type of string)
Setting 'theia.frontend.config.cliVersion' application configuration value to: "0.35.3" (type of string)
Setting 'theia.frontend.config.buildDate' application configuration value to: "2024-02-20T10:04:35.814Z" (type of string)
Frontend application configuration after modifications: {"applicationName":"Arduino IDE","defaultTheme":{"light":"arduino-theme","dark":"arduino-theme-dark"},"defaultIconTheme":"none","electron":{"windowOptions":{}},"defaultLocale":"","validatePreferencesSchema":false,"preferences":{"window.title":"${rootName}${activeEditorShort}${appName}","files.autoSave":"afterDelay","editor.minimap.enabled":false,"editor.tabSize":2,"editor.scrollBeyondLastLine":false,"editor.quickSuggestions":{"other":false,"comments":false,"strings":false},"editor.maxTokenizationLineLength":500,"editor.bracketPairColorization.enabled":false,"breadcrumbs.enabled":false,"workbench.tree.renderIndentGuides":"none","explorer.compactFolders":false},"appVersion":"2.3.2","cliVersion":"0.35.3","buildDate":"2024-02-20T10:04:35.814Z"}
Starting backend process. PID: 20372
Using browser-only version of superagent in non-browser environment
Configuration directory URI: 'file:///c%3A/Users/jmwau/.arduinoIDE'
Configuring to accept webviews on '^.+\.webview\..+$' hostname.
2024-05-13T19:57:22.348Z root INFO Backend Object.initialize: 4.8 ms [Finished 0.487 s after backend start]
2024-05-13T19:57:22.349Z root INFO Backend Object.configure: 4.0 ms [Finished 0.487 s after backend start]
2024-05-13T19:57:22.349Z root INFO Backend s.onStart: 2.1 ms [Finished 0.487 s after backend start]
2024-05-13T19:57:22.350Z root INFO Backend s.configure: 0.3 ms [Finished 0.512 s after backend start]
2024-05-13T19:57:22.351Z root INFO Backend d.onStart: 0.2 ms [Finished 0.512 s after backend start]
2024-05-13T19:57:22.352Z root INFO Backend d.configure: 0.1 ms [Finished 0.512 s after backend start]
2024-05-13T19:57:22.352Z root INFO Backend d.initialize: 25.1 ms [Finished 0.513 s after backend start]
2024-05-13T19:57:22.353Z root INFO Backend c.onStart: 0.3 ms [Finished 0.513 s after backend start]
2024-05-13T19:57:22.353Z root INFO Backend a.configure: 1.2 ms [Finished 0.514 s after backend start]
2024-05-13T19:57:22.355Z config INFO >>> Initializing CLI configuration...
2024-05-13T19:57:22.355Z root INFO Backend c.initialize: 0.9 ms [Finished 0.515 s after backend start]
2024-05-13T19:57:22.355Z root INFO Backend R.onStart: 0.9 ms [Finished 0.515 s after backend start]
2024-05-13T19:57:22.356Z config INFO Loading CLI configuration from c:\Users\jmwau\.arduinoIDE\arduino-cli.yaml...
2024-05-13T19:57:22.356Z daemon INFO Starting daemon from C:\Program Files\Arduino IDE\resources\app\lib\backend\resources\arduino-cli.exe...
2024-05-13T19:57:22.356Z root INFO Backend a.initialize: 0.4 ms [Finished 0.516 s after backend start]
2024-05-13T19:57:22.356Z root INFO Backend w.onStart: 1.1 ms [Finished 0.517 s after backend start]
2024-05-13T19:57:22.356Z root INFO Backend r.configure: 1.9 ms [Finished 0.517 s after backend start]
2024-05-13T19:57:22.356Z discovery-log INFO start
2024-05-13T19:57:22.356Z discovery-log INFO start new deferred
2024-05-13T19:57:22.356Z root INFO Backend d.initialize: 0.5 ms [Finished 0.518 s after backend start]
2024-05-13T19:57:22.357Z root INFO Backend y.onStart: 2.0 ms [Finished 0.519 s after backend start]
2024-05-13T19:57:22.357Z root INFO Backend r.configure: 1.7 ms [Finished 0.520 s after backend start]
2024-05-13T19:57:22.357Z root INFO Backend a.onStart: 0.5 ms [Finished 0.521 s after backend start]
2024-05-13T19:57:22.357Z root INFO Backend h.configure: 0.4 ms [Finished 0.521 s after backend start]
2024-05-13T19:57:22.357Z root INFO Backend s.configure: 0.2 ms [Finished 0.521 s after backend start]
2024-05-13T19:57:22.357Z root INFO Backend l.configure: 0.1 ms [Finished 0.521 s after backend start]
2024-05-13T19:57:22.359Z root INFO Theia app listening on http://127.0.0.1:63045.
2024-05-13T19:57:22.359Z root INFO Finished starting backend application: 2.8 ms [Finished 0.524 s after backend start]
2024-05-13T19:57:22.367Z root WARN The local plugin referenced by local-dir:/c%3A/Users/jmwau/.arduinoIDE/plugins does not exist.
2024-05-13T19:57:22.367Z root WARN The local plugin referenced by local-dir:/c%3A/Users/jmwau/.arduinoIDE/extensions does not exist.
2024-05-13T19:57:22.367Z root WARN The local plugin referenced by local-dir:C:\Users\jmwau\.arduinoIDE\plugins does not exist.
2024-05-13T19:57:22.374Z config INFO Loaded CLI configuration: {"board_manager":{"additional_urls":[]},"build_cache":{"compilations_before_purge":10,"ttl":"720h0m0s"},"daemon":{"port":"50051"},"directories":{"data":"C:\\Users\\jmwau\\AppData\\Local\\Arduino15","downloads":"C:\\Users\\jmwau\\AppData\\Local\\Arduino15\\staging","user":"C:\\Users\\jmwau\\OneDrive\\Documents\\Arduino"},"library":{"enable_unsafe_install":false},"logging":{"file":"","format":"text","level":"info"},"metrics":{"addr":":9090","enabled":true},"output":{"no_color":false},"sketch":{"always_export_binaries":false},"updater":{"enable_notification":true}}
2024-05-13T19:57:22.374Z config INFO 'directories.data' and 'directories.user' are set in the CLI configuration model.
2024-05-13T19:57:22.374Z config INFO Loaded the CLI configuration.
2024-05-13T19:57:22.377Z config INFO Mapped the CLI configuration: {"dataDirUri":"file:///c%3A/Users/jmwau/AppData/Local/Arduino15","sketchDirUri":"file:///c%3A/Users/jmwau/OneDrive/Documents/Arduino","additionalUrls":[],"network":"none","locale":"en"}
2024-05-13T19:57:22.377Z config INFO Validating the CLI configuration...
2024-05-13T19:57:22.377Z config INFO The CLI config is valid.
2024-05-13T19:57:22.377Z config INFO <<< Initialized the CLI configuration.
2024-05-13T19:57:22.399Z root INFO Resolve plugins list: 43.4 ms [Finished 0.563 s after backend start]
2024-05-13T19:57:22.445Z daemon INFO time="2024-05-13T12:57:22-07:00" level=info msg="Using config file: c:\\Users\\jmwau\\.arduinoIDE\\arduino-cli.yaml"
time="2024-05-13T12:57:22-07:00" level=info msg="arduino-cli.exe version 0.35.3"
time="2024-05-13T12:57:22-07:00" level=info msg="Executing `arduino-cli daemon`"
Daemon is now listening on 127.0.0.1:63046
{"IP":"127.0.0.1","Port":"63046"}
2024-05-13T19:57:22.445Z daemon INFO Daemon is running.
2024-05-13T19:57:22.504Z daemon INFO time="2024-05-13T12:57:22-07:00" level=info msg="Updating libraries index"
2024-05-13T19:57:22.505Z daemon INFO time="2024-05-13T12:57:22-07:00" level=info msg="Starting download" url="https://downloads.arduino.cc/libraries/library_index.tar.bz2"
2024-05-13T19:57:23.068Z root INFO Deploy plugins list: 43.4 ms [Finished 1.233 s after backend start]
Opening channel for service path '/services/electron-window'.
Opening channel for service path '/services/ide-updater'.
2024-05-13T19:57:23.951Z root WARN Frontend a.configure took longer than the expected maximum 100 milliseconds: 137.5 ms [Finished 1.504 s after frontend start]
2024-05-13T19:57:23.951Z root WARN A command editor.action.toggleStickyScroll is already registered.
2024-05-13T19:57:24.661Z root ERROR Detected an error response during the gRPC core client initialization: code: 3, message: Error verifying signature: openpgp: signature expired
2024-05-13T19:57:24.669Z daemon INFO time="2024-05-13T12:57:24-07:00" level=info msg="Checking signature" index="C:\\Users\\jmwau\\AppData\\Local\\Arduino15\\package_index.json" signatureFile="C:\\Users\\jmwau\\AppData\\Local\\Arduino15\\package_index.json.sig" trusted=true
2024-05-13T19:57:24.670Z daemon INFO time="2024-05-13T12:57:24-07:00" level=info msg="Loading hardware from: C:\\Users\\jmwau\\AppData\\Local\\Arduino15\\packages"
2024-05-13T19:57:24.671Z daemon INFO time="2024-05-13T12:57:24-07:00" level=info msg="Loading package builtin from: C:\\Users\\jmwau\\AppData\\Local\\Arduino15\\packages\\builtin"
time="2024-05-13T12:57:24-07:00" level=info msg="Checking existence of 'tools' path: C:\\Users\\jmwau\\AppData\\Local\\Arduino15\\packages\\builtin\\tools"
time="2024-05-13T12:57:24-07:00" level=info msg="Loading tools from dir: C:\\Users\\jmwau\\AppData\\Local\\Arduino15\\packages\\builtin\\tools"
time="2024-05-13T12:57:24-07:00" level=info msg="Loaded tool" tool="builtin:ctags@5.8-arduino11"
time="2024-05-13T12:57:24-07:00" level=info msg="Loaded tool" tool="builtin:dfu-discovery@0.1.2"
time="2024-05-13T12:57:24-07:00" level=info msg="Loaded tool" tool="builtin:mdns-discovery@1.0.9"
2024-05-13T19:57:24.671Z daemon INFO time="2024-05-13T12:57:24-07:00" level=info msg="Loaded tool" tool="builtin:serial-discovery@1.4.0"
2024-05-13T19:57:24.671Z daemon INFO time="2024-05-13T12:57:24-07:00" level=info msg="Loaded tool" tool="builtin:serial-monitor@0.14.1"
2024-05-13T19:57:24.671Z daemon INFO time="2024-05-13T12:57:24-07:00" level=info msg="Loading libraries index file" index="C:\\Users\\jmwau\\AppData\\Local\\Arduino15\\library_index.json"
2024-05-13T19:57:24.672Z daemon INFO time="2024-05-13T12:57:24-07:00" level=info msg="Adding libraries dir" dir="C:\\Users\\jmwau\\AppData\\Local\\Arduino15\\libraries" location=ide
2024-05-13T19:57:24.672Z daemon INFO time="2024-05-13T12:57:24-07:00" level=info msg="Adding libraries dir" dir="C:\\Users\\jmwau\\OneDrive\\Documents\\Arduino\\libraries" location=user
2024-05-13T19:57:24.673Z root ERROR Detected an error response during the gRPC core client initialization: code: 9, message: Loading index file: reading library_index.json: open C:\Users\jmwau\AppData\Local\Arduino15\library_index.json: The system cannot find the file specified.
2024-05-13T19:57:24.678Z root ERROR The primary packages indexes are missing. Running indexes update before initializing the core gRPC client The index of the cores and libraries must be updated before initializing the core gRPC client.
The following problems were detected during the gRPC client initialization:
[library-index] - code: 9, message: Loading index file: reading library_index.json: open C:\Users\jmwau\AppData\Local\Arduino15\library_index.json: The system cannot find the file specified.

2024-05-13T19:57:24.679Z daemon INFO time="2024-05-13T12:57:24-07:00" level=info msg="Updating libraries index"
2024-05-13T19:57:24.680Z daemon INFO time="2024-05-13T12:57:24-07:00" level=info msg="Starting download" url="https://downloads.arduino.cc/libraries/library_index.tar.bz2"
2024-05-13T19:57:24.681Z root INFO core-client-provider [library-index] Downloading index: library_index.tar.bz2

2024-05-13T19:57:27.210Z daemon INFO time="2024-05-13T12:57:27-07:00" level=info msg="Updating libraries index"
2024-05-13T19:57:27.212Z daemon INFO time="2024-05-13T12:57:27-07:00" level=info msg="Starting download" url="https://downloads.arduino.cc/libraries/library_index.tar.bz2"
2024-05-13T19:57:29.772Z root ERROR Detected an error response during the gRPC core client initialization: code: 3, message: Error verifying signature: openpgp: signature expired
2024-05-13T19:57:29.780Z daemon INFO time="2024-05-13T12:57:29-07:00" level=info msg="Checking signature" index="C:\\Users\\jmwau\\AppData\\Local\\Arduino15\\package_index.json" signatureFile="C:\\Users\\jmwau\\AppData\\Local\\Arduino15\\package_index.json.sig" trusted=true
2024-05-13T19:57:29.784Z daemon INFO time="2024-05-13T12:57:29-07:00" level=info msg="Loading hardware from: C:\\Users\\jmwau\\AppData\\Local\\Arduino15\\packages"
2024-05-13T19:57:29.786Z daemon INFO time="2024-05-13T12:57:29-07:00" level=info msg="Loading package builtin from: C:\\Users\\jmwau\\AppData\\Local\\Arduino15\\packages\\builtin"
time="2024-05-13T12:57:29-07:00" level=info msg="Checking existence of 'tools' path: C:\\Users\\jmwau\\AppData\\Local\\Arduino15\\packages\\builtin\\tools"
time="2024-05-13T12:57:29-07:00" level=info msg="Loading tools from dir: C:\\Users\\jmwau\\AppData\\Local\\Arduino15\\packages\\builtin\\tools"
time="2024-05-13T12:57:29-07:00" level=info msg="Loaded tool" tool="builtin:ctags@5.8-arduino11"
time="2024-05-13T12:57:29-07:00" level=info msg="Loaded tool" tool="builtin:dfu-discovery@0.1.2"
time="2024-05-13T12:57:29-07:00" level=info msg="Loaded tool" tool="builtin:mdns-discovery@1.0.9"
time="2024-05-13T12:57:29-07:00" level=info msg="Loaded tool" tool="builtin:serial-discovery@1.4.0"
time="2024-05-13T12:57:29-07:00" level=info msg="Loaded tool" tool="builtin:serial-monitor@0.14.1"
time="2024-05-13T12:57:29-07:00" level=info msg="Loading libraries index file" index="C:\\Users\\jmwau\\AppData\\Local\\Arduino15\\library_index.json"
time="2024-05-13T12:57:29-07:00" level=info msg="Adding libraries dir" dir="C:\\Users\\jmwau\\AppData\\Local\\Arduino15\\libraries" location=ide
time="2024-05-13T12:57:29-07:00" level=info msg="Adding libraries dir" dir="C:\\Users\\jmwau\\OneDrive\\Documents\\Arduino\\libraries" location=user
2024-05-13T19:57:29.786Z root ERROR Detected an error response during the gRPC core client initialization: code: 9, message: Loading index file: reading library_index.json: open C:\Users\jmwau\AppData\Local\Arduino15\library_index.json: The system cannot find the file specified.
2024-05-13T19:57:29.786Z root ERROR Uncaught Exception:  Error: The index of the cores and libraries must be updated before initializing the core gRPC client.
The following problems were detected during the gRPC client initialization:
[library-index] - code: 9, message: Loading index file: reading library_index.json: open C:\Users\jmwau\AppData\Local\Arduino15\library_index.json: The system cannot find the file specified.

2024-05-13T19:57:29.786Z root ERROR Error: The index of the cores and libraries must be updated before initializing the core gRPC client.
The following problems were detected during the gRPC client initialization:
[library-index] - code: 9, message: Loading index file: reading library_index.json: open C:\Users\jmwau\AppData\Local\Arduino15\library_index.json: The system cannot find the file specified.

    at C:\Program Files\Arduino IDE\resources\app\lib\backend\main.js:2:622877
    at E.evaluateErrorStatus (C:\Program Files\Arduino IDE\resources\app\lib\backend\main.js:2:622893)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async a.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\Arduino IDE\resources\app\lib\backend\main.js:2:622563)
Closing channel on service path '/services/electron-window'.
Closing channel on service path '/services/ide-updater'.
Stored workspaces roots:
No sketches were scheduled for deletion.



2024-05-13T19:57:29.772Z root ERROR Detected an error response during the gRPC core client initialization: code: 3, message: Error verifying signature: openpgp: signature expired

This "Error verifying signature: openpgp: signature expired" error occurs when your system time is incorrect. You can fix it by syncing the system time.
I'll provide instructions you can follow to do that:

Right click the Windows Start icon (⊞) on the taskbar.
A context menu will open.
Select "Settings" from the context menu.
Windows "Settings" will open.
Select "Time & language" from the navigation panel on the left side of the window.
Select "Date & time" from the list on the right side of the Settings window.
The Date & time settings section will expand.
Click the "Sync now" button that is under the "Additional settings" section of the page.
Wait for the time syncing process to finish.
Close any Arduino IDE windows that are open.
Start Arduino IDE again.

This time Arduino IDE should start up fully and work as expected.

I have this same issue except the fix noted above does not work for me. I just get a constant pulsing Arduino logo.

@TexasT this answer is specific to the case where startup hangs AND the "Error verifying signature: openpgp: signature expired" error message is present in the logs. There are other causes of Arduino IDE startup hanging. Since you don't have enough information to formulate a high quality Stack Exchange question, please request assistance over on https://forum.arduino.cc/. That will be a more suitable platform for supporting you.
